# Codeigniter Share Link with Facebook?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

Helloe Friends i create a project with codeigniter. i already create a login with facebook.

but i want to share link link on facebook.

means client is click on share with facebook. then the link share on client facebook as a post.

thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the Facebook documentation already? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/
Please share some of the (relevant) code that is causing you trouble, describe the exact problem and we'll try to help you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share things on Facebook with just a hyperlink. Something like this should do the trick:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[summary]=SUMMARY&p[url]=URL&p[title]=TITLE
```

where SUMMARY is your summary of the link, TITLE is the title you want to show, and URL is the URL.

You will also need to encode this data using `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can share link on facebook by simply creating a link.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[EncodedURL]
```

your link will be like:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[EncodedURL-URl you want to share]" target="_blank">share</a>
```

Or if you want a popup window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function genericSocialShare(url){
     window.open(url,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=648,height=395');
     return true;
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:genericSocialShare('[CustomSocialShareLink]')">[Social Media Share Text/Image]</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can Share Webpages with Facebook by this method

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL

**Example**

I want to share my website post on Facebook just need to place the URL in this link supose I have this post I want to share on Facebook

```
https://justhinter.com/typedef-and-union-in-c-programming/
```

now I just need to replace  with this post URL you can check by clicking the link

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://justhinter.com/typedef-and-union-in-c-programming/

**This url used to accept Parameters such as title and description, but they are no longer supported and should not be used.**